# Cypress: How to properly close a mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material, automated-tests, cypress

So I'm using Cypress for testing our Angular application, but for some reason I always have an issue with closing mat-select components which are multiselect. Has anyone got a good solution for this?

```
function selectValue(id: string, value: string) {
    return cy.get(`mat-select[id="${id}"]`)
             .click()
             .then(() => 
                cy.get('mat-option')
                  .contains(value)
                  .click();
}
```

Comment: Why you're calling click in then?

Comment: Why are you using a function here?
You should add code you want to re-use in support/commands.js

There you should call it like you would call the commands normally, you aren't supposed to use .then(), you should chain the commands normally.

Comment: @PrzemyslawJanBeigert Not sure I understand your question? First click() is to open the dropdown and the second is to select a value. Preferably I would use select() instead of click() but it does not seem to support mat-select. This approach works well enough on a mat-select which is single-select.

Comment: @G-M Agreed, I haven't really been critical where I have placed my commands. Chaining them how you suggest is probably more correct, although it does not help close the dialog

Answer (score 11):

To close the list on a multi-select dropdown, do what a user does and click outside the list, e.g on the body

```js
it('selects, closes, verifies', () => {

  cy.visit('https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection')

  cy.get('div[role="listbox"]').should('not.exist')    // check list isn't open    

  cy.get('select-multiple-example').click()            // open
  cy.get('div[role="listbox"]').should('exist')        // check list is open    

  cy.contains('Extra cheese').click()                  // select an item
  cy.contains('Onion').click()                         // select an item
  cy.contains('Tomato').click()                        // select an item

  cy.get('body').click()                               // click outside the list

  cy.get('div[role="listbox"]').should('not.exist')    // check list isn't open    
  
  cy.get('select-multiple-example')
    .should('contain', 'Extra cheese, Onion, Tomato')  // verify
    
  cy.get('select-multiple-example')
    .should('not.contain', 'Mushroom')                 // verify contra
    
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the selection list is on the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 6):

Another thing that worked in my case was

```
cy.get(`mat-select[data-testid="${dropdownTestId}"]`).focus().type('{esc}');
```

Comment: This is the best solution. If I click on the body as the selected answer, it would close the modal where I'm working.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest something like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('selectValue', (value) => {
  cy
      .get('mat-select').first().click()
      .get('.mat-option-text').contains(value).click()
      .get('.mat-option-text').should('not.visible')
      .get('.mat-select-value-text').first().should(([{ innerText }]) => {
        expect(innerText).equal(value)
      })
});
```

I tested it on https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview and it works on my local machine.

If something fails, feel free to ask questions

Comment: Looks good, will try it later on. I'm somehow unsure if it would work on a multiselect though. Have you tried it on [multiselect](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection) specifically?

Comment: No, I tried only on single select. Try on multiselect, and feel free to ask if something will be wrong

Comment: The approach works for me, thanks for sharing! Especially checking afterwards that the element has been selected, helped me a lot, and also waiting until the option has disappeared - just had to adapt that not the first elements are selected but the ones I explicitly needed.

Answer (score 2):

in my case it was not possible to click outside of the select box because overlay issue is blocking everything, for my case this "weird solution" worked:

```
cy.get('mat-option').contains(text).click().type('{end}').type('{esc}');
```

Comment: Clicking the overlay should also have the same effect.

Comment: This seems best. Worked for me. The mat-select overlay does prevent the body click from working.

Answer (score 1):

A better way is to use the new feature components harnesses

https://material.angular.io/cdk/test-harnesses/overview

for your problem it should work like this, first you create harness loader from the fixture in beforeEach statement

```
loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
```

then you can get the select harness by doing something like this

```
let selectHarness = await loader.getHarness(MatSelectHarness.with({selector: '#select-id'}));
```

now you can simply use the close method

```
selectHarness.close()
```

Comment: Is there a way to use `TestbedHarnessEnvironment` with Cypress? I guess that it's already in node_modules if Angular Material is installed. How do we import it into the test?

Comment: you can get the fixture like this `fixture = TestBed.createComponent(JobsCarouselSectionCreatorComponent);` also add it in beforeEach block. I am assuming you are using Angular TestBed for your tests, if not check this example for how to prepare the fixture https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#query-for-the-h1

Comment: for Cypress i found this library to deal with harness 
https://github.com/jscutlery/test-utils/tree/master/packages/cypress-harness
sorry i am not an expert of Cypress, but the library looks fine

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll give it a try - will post the steps if I work it out.

Comment: If I remember TestBed, it looks more like **component testing** than e2e (i.e `createComponent()` rather than referencing the live browser DOM).

Comment: @RichardMatsen you are right, i totally missed that Cypress is used to 2e2 tests, by bad

Comment: Well actually there's a push towards component testing in Cypress see [My Vision for Component Tests in Cypress](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/my-vision-for-component-tests/). Same author has a `mount()` for [Angular components here](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-angular-unit-test), ***Under the hood, it's based on TestBed***.